# Make a summary by collecting all sub-title

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, summary

I would like to make a summary that allows you to retrieve all the h2s on a page and then make them clickable by making an anchor.

I have already made the code to retrieve them and display them in a div.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var x = document.querySelectorAll("#content-article h2");
    for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        var content = x[i].innerHTML;
        document.getElementById('result').innerHTML += '<a href="#">'+content+'</a>';
    }
});
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `h2` titles need to have an `id` like so:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#content-article").find('h2').each(function(index, h2) {
      var id = $(h2).attr('id');
      var title = $(h2).text();
      $("#result").append('<a href="#'+id+'">'+title+'</a>');
    });
});
```

```css
a {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="result"></div>
<div id="content-article">
    <h2 id="first-section">My first section</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed at dictum nisi, a fringilla purus. Curabitur mi odio, pellentesque a cursus a, fermentum vitae velit. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Sed porta varius magna et sodales. In porttitor massa a sapien imperdiet, sed dapibus leo aliquet. Etiam vitae ligula aliquam sem maximus laoreet eu a felis. In scelerisque metus molestie dignissim maximus. Morbi aliquet, justo nec vestibulum scelerisque, tortor eros porta nisl, id dapibus massa leo vel ex.</p>
    <h2 id="second-section">My second section</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed at dictum nisi, a fringilla purus. Curabitur mi odio, pellentesque a cursus a, fermentum vitae velit. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Sed porta varius magna et sodales. In porttitor massa a sapien imperdiet, sed dapibus leo aliquet. Etiam vitae ligula aliquam sem maximus laoreet eu a felis. In scelerisque metus molestie dignissim maximus. Morbi aliquet, justo nec vestibulum scelerisque, tortor eros porta nisl, id dapibus massa leo vel ex.</p>
</div>
```

Need more context! Do you want a `summary` tag?